# imagecreatefromstring failed when large image

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a code for crop uploaded image.

```
$fh = fopen($source, "rb") or die();
$buffer = 1024*1024;
while (!feof($fh)) { 
  $freadedimage=fread($fh, $buffer); 
  flush();
}
fclose($fh);

$sourceImg = imagecreatefromstring($freadedimage);
if ($sourceImg === false) {
  throw new Exception("Invalid image.");
}
```

When file is not so big (approx. 300-900 Kb) all gone excellent. But, when file size is more than 2 Mb I got the error:

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognised format

I tried to use file_get_contents instead of fread - works perfectly. But only in case of ini_set('memory_limit', '64M' ). But this variant is not for me, because I have a restrictions on host.

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Every time around your `while` loop you keep overwriting the beginning of your buffer because you are not moving your pointer along by the number of bytes you read.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't complain if the image file size is more than 1,048,576 bytes, ie 1024*1024

Comment: is there a reason you are not using the functions `imagecreatefromjpeg`, `imagecreatefromgif`, and `imagecreatefrompng`?

Comment: thank you for information, I'll review above functions, maybe will be easier to use them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the file in chunks of 1024*1024 bytes, but if the file is larger than that then each iteration of the loop is overwriting what has already been read

```
$freadedimage = '';
while (!feof($fh)) { 
    $freadedimage .= fread($fh, $buffer); 
    flush();
}
```